# how to customize fb-like button and post_data

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I am using the fb-like widget by facebook in my site. I want it to render image of the post and description when they like it and that like needs to render on to the facebook wall that they liked it. But fb-like is just showing the link as the description and header on the wall.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the Open Graph metatags to your page. Read step 2 in the [Like button social plugin docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) for a guide to creating these tags. This will ensure that your page appears correctly in posts.